# how do you paint faces inside of columns and in-place families?

Tags: paint, revit-api, revit

I´m creating an add-in for painting faces, mostly works fine, i´m using **doc.Paint(eId, face, SelectedMaterial.Id)**; but i dont know how to paint inside in-place families and in occasions faces within "Column" category elements does not get painted. ¿Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to paint an actual face?  Or you're trying to paint the face of an element?

Comment: I want to paint faces inside FamilyInstances and an In-place Families

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as if the FaceSplitter class might come in handy for this:

http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/ba55587f-4f1e-7f4c-5b1c-864e10cab304.htm

Here are some hints on how to use it:

http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-A7308E03-F3C3-433E-8AD5-3C31EDD81387

Here is another related discussion on splitting a wall using the Revit API:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/split-wall-using-revit-api/td-p/6562014

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What i want is to paint existing faces inside Family instances and In-Place Families. I have not managed to do it right. In FamilyInstances, they does not get painted unless at least one face from the instance was painted before (so does not work for newly created instances). In In-Place Families i can´t get them painted at all.